# Do I need to add gradle import in Android Studio for Fabric Answers if I'm already using Crashlytics?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

Android Studio, Gradle, Fabric Crashlytics - we've got a pretty common setup. We have the usual `compile` line in `build.gradle`:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

And in our `Application` sub-class, the instantiating line:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

All good. Working for a long time. Now we want to use Fabric Answers.

Here's the confusing part - if I edit the instantiating line to this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Answers());
```

.. it **works**. I was expecting that I would **need** to add the following to `build.gradle`, as their installation docs recommend:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

But the `Answers` class seems to be found with or without this import.

So, I guess my questions:

1. Do I need **both** Gradle `compile` entries? Or is `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar` a super-set that already includes Answers?
2. Is `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new Answers());` the correct way to instantiate things when I want both Crashlytics + Answers?

I'm using *both* Gradle imports, but it just seemed to compile OK even if I didn't have the second one. Kinda confused why.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As the accepted answer states, having `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` alone is enough.

Digging into the `Crashlytics` class, it looks like it actually instantiates a few things:

`this(new Answers(), new Beta(), new CrashlyticsCore());`

.. so there you go! The extra Gradle import + Fabric instantiation argument are superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly add the Answers dependency to the build.gradle file since it's already included by default with Fabric. So your first line is fine `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

Comment: Which is exactly what it was before we decided to use "Answers". What about the extra Gradle import? Is it *also* not needed?

Comment: Correct. I just have the first Gradle import in my projects and that includes both Fabric and Answers.

Comment: Ah cool. Dug into the `Crashlytics` class and it makes sense now. Accepting your answer.